# Coloured Background of Action Button in Sweet Alert (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, sweetalert

I have written some code for showing a Dialog box using sweet alert library. It's a very popular library and contains couple of awesome features which are very useful for designing purpose and developing purpose as well. So please help to change the background color of Action button which are present at the bottom of the dialog box.

I am attaching the screen shot and as well as code. Please help me to fix this issue.

I only want to change the background color of Action Button.

```
 MaterialDialog.Builder builder = new MaterialDialog.Builder(SignInActivity.this)
                                     .title("Sign Up")
                                     .titleColor(Color.BLACK)
                                     .customView(R.layout.custom_dialog_sign_up, true)
                                     .positiveText("Submit")
                                     .negativeText("Cancel")
                                     .positiveColorRes(R.color.black_color)
                                     .negativeColorRes(R.color.gray_btn_bg_color)
                                     .canceledOnTouchOutside(false)
                                     .autoDismiss(false);

    final MaterialDialog materialDialog = builder.build();

    materialDialog.show();
```

Comment: You didn't attach a screenshot and the code doesn't look like from Sweet Alert library, so also post link to the library you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is pretty late to respond upon your question but, recently i face this issue and start digging about it on google but found nothing, so i started my own and found this perfect solution code and screen shot attached.

[image]

```
SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialogView;
sweetAlertDialogView = new SweetAlertDialog(ctx,SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE);
 sweetAlertDialogView.setTitleText(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_oops_title))
                    .setContentText("Request failed :" + errMsg + " \n" + ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_check_net_connection));
            sweetAlertDialogView.show();
            Button viewGroup = (Button) sweetAlertDialogView.findViewById(cn.pedant.SweetAlert.R.id.confirm_button);
            if (viewGroup != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "showErrorMsg: Button view Found yep");
                viewGroup.setBackgroundColor(viewGroup.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSkyBlueButtonLoader));
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "showErrorMsg: Button view Null :( ");
            }
```

from above logic i update the button color to dark sky blue blue, for any other help you can ask me in comment. i will try to resolve it with my best.

Answer (score 1):

A far more easier way to accomplish this is to just overwrite following color values in your color.xml:

```
<color name="blue_btn_bg_color">#1976D2</color>
<color name="blue_btn_bg_pressed_color">#1565C0</color>
```